# Visual Studio stuck on fullscreen UWP app error

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, win2d

When debugging a fullscreen Win2d UWP app from VS and my code has an error, the app window gets frozen "always-on-top" style, forcing me to reboot or log out of windows. The app was still showing the blue startup image with no top bar access.

I tried Alt+F4, Shift+Win+Enter, Alt+Tab. The app stays fullscreen and on top even after closing it. The Win key reveals the taskbar but closing VS fails because it creates an unreachable confirmation dialog about stopping the debugger. Task manager is also unusable, hidden behind the frozen app. I've removed this line for now, but I want to start in fullscreen always.

```
ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.FullScreen;
```

Here's example code using the Win2d quick start guide that causes the problem for me:

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="Example.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Example"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:canvas="using:Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid>
        <canvas:CanvasControl x:Name="canvas" Draw="canvas_Draw"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml;
using System;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace Example
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.FullScreen;
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void canvas_Draw(CanvasControl sender, CanvasDrawEventArgs args)
        {
            throw new Exception("error in my code");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "the code has an error" mean? I used `ApplicationViewWindowingMode.FullScreen` method to full screen uwp, when the mouse move to the top of application, it will display titlebar to allow us to close the application. I can't reproduce this issue, so can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT I meant an error in my own code. I edited it and added the sample code. I also noticed it doesn't freeze when I run without debugging.

Comment: When you run it without debugging, it doesn't have debugger attached with it and if you set any breakpoint within the code, application won’t pause. Why do you throw an exception in canvas_Draw event? If you don't want the app stuck, you can first exit full screen by using `ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().ExitFullScreenMode();` and then throw the exception. If you do that, can it solve your issue?